# How to convert node readable stream to RX observable

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

If I have a Node js stream, say for example from something like `process.stdin` or from `fs.createReadStream`, how can I convert this to be an RxJs Observable stream using RxJs5?

I see that [RxJs-Node](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx-node) has a `fromReadableStream` method, but that looks like it hasn't been updated in close to a year.

Comment: so does it work or? Who cares how often it is updated if it works

Comment: @smnbbrv No doubt it works just fine, but it's RxJS4 and is not compatible with RxJS5.

Comment: You could have a look at [the source](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node/blob/master/index.js#L45-L83) to see what it would take to convert it yourself - the implementation is pretty small.

Comment: RxJS has changed so much over the past few versions, if anyone is reading this, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74925985/314114) below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For anyone looking for this, following Mark's recommendation, I adapted rx-node `fromStream` implementation for rxjs5.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// Adapted from https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node/blob/87589c07be626c32c842bdafa782fca5924e749c/index.js#L52
export default function fromStream(stream, finishEventName = 'end', dataEventName = 'data') {
  stream.pause();

  return new Observable((observer) => {
    function dataHandler(data) {
      observer.next(data);
    }

    function errorHandler(err) {
      observer.error(err);
    }

    function endHandler() {
      observer.complete();
    }

    stream.addListener(dataEventName, dataHandler);
    stream.addListener('error', errorHandler);
    stream.addListener(finishEventName, endHandler);

    stream.resume();

    return () => {
      stream.removeListener(dataEventName, dataHandler);
      stream.removeListener('error', errorHandler);
      stream.removeListener(finishEventName, endHandler);
    };
  }).share();
}
```

Note that it intrinsically breaks all back pressure functionalities of streams. Observables' are a push technology. All input chunks are going to be read and pushed to the observer as quickly as possible. Depending on your case, it might not be the best solution.

Comment: I haven't tested this since I moved on from what I was working on, but if anyone else has and it worked, I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: I am using it and so far it is working well. I have not unit tested it thought.

Answer (score 5):

Since Node v11.14.0 streams support `for await`
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_symbol_asynciterator

it means you can pass **stream** to `from()` operator.

Under hood rxjs(v7.x.x) will call `fromAsyncIterable()` that will return **Observable**

Answer (score 3):

The following should work for both v4 and v5 (*disclaimer* untested):

```
fromStream: function (stream, finishEventName, dataEventName) {
    stream.pause();

    finishEventName || (finishEventName = 'end');
    dataEventName || (dataEventName = 'data');

    return Observable.create(function (observer) {

      // This is the "next" event
      const data$ = Observable.fromEvent(stream, dataEventName);

      // Map this into an error event
      const error$ = Observable.fromEvent(stream, 'error')
        .flatMap(err => Observable.throw(err));

      // Shut down the stream
      const complete$ = Observable.fromEvent(stream, finishEventName);

      // Put it all together and subscribe
      const sub = data$
        .merge(error$)
        .takeUntil(complete$)
        .subscribe(observer);

      // Start the underlying node stream
      stream.resume();

      // Return a handle to destroy the stream
      return sub;
    })

    // Avoid recreating the stream on duplicate subscriptions
    .share();
  },
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers above will work, though the don't support backpressure. If you are trying to read a large file with createReadStream, they will read the whole thing in memory.

Here is my implementation with backpressure support:
[rxjs-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nitedani/rxjs-stream)

Comment: Checked out your code bc I'm interested in backpressure on streams in RxJS. It doesn't look like you do that, however, unless I've misread your code. Instead, it looks like you've introduced a delay, which is not backpressure. Did I misunderstand something? Thank you.

Comment: I've discovered issues with my code since my answer. It does pause the underlying Node stream(stream.on('data')), but only unpauses it when the current processed value is emitted in observable.subscribe. The main issue with this is, that in RxJs there are operators that interrupt the flow of a stream. For example, the bufferCount operator collects values over time, which can cause .subscribe not called for every value - and not unpausing the underlying Node stream. Proper backpressure support for all operators would be very involved. RxJs would need to add first-party support for this.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone coming here recently (RxJS 7 & Node 18+) should use the following code.

Why does this work? RxJS has been updated to handle stream like objects. When you pass a ReadStream to RxJS, it tests if it is `ReadableStreamLike` and then turns it into an `AsyncGenerator`.

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const file = fs.createReadStream(fileName);

const file$ = from(file).subscribe({
  next:  (dat) => { ... },
  error: (err) => { ... },
  complete: () => { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The RxJs-Node implementation is RxJs4 based but can be ported to RxJs5 without much work https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx-node/blob/87589c07be626c32c842bdafa782fca5924e749c/index.js#L52

Comment: thanks, so it sounds like you would have to implement a conversion?

Comment: It seems there is no rxjs5 version out yet so for now yes

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to read from a csv file, the following method is the cleanest implementation that I have found to return and observable with the data parsed into objects.

In this example I used a tab sepperated file, but you can also use this approach for csv files. It uses [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) to map data onto the right interface.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { parse } from 'csv-parse';
import type { Parser } from 'csv-parse';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Columns {
  columnA: string;
  columnB: string;
}

function readTabFile(): Observable<Columns[]> {
  const parser: Parser = parse({
    delimiter: '\t',
    columns: ['columnA', 'columnB'],
  });
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    const lines: Columns[] = [];
    const stream = fs.createReadStream('./file.TAB', {
      encoding: 'utf8',
    });

    parser.on('data', (row: Columns) => {
      lines.push(row);
    });

    parser.on('end', () => {
      observer.next(lines);
      observer.complete();
    });

    stream.pipe(parser);
  });
}
```